# Reasons and uses to show and print a level on a binary search tree?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I had class yesterday for data structures and my professor was discussing the uses of binary trees, and some info on its levels. I'm starting to work on creating a binary search tree, and I want to include a print function to display level on a tree
Tree example:

- 3 is root. 3 has two childs, to the left is 2 and and its right is 5.
- 2 has a child node to its left, 1.
- 5 has 2 child nodes. 4 is its left child node and 6 is the right child node.
- I want to print level 1 of the tree (the 2 and 5)

`3
        /   \
       2     5
      /    /   \
     1    4     6`

I want to have a print function in my program to show a level in a tree, but I need some reason for doing that (my professor wants a reason, idk why and i didnt ask). Any reasons to show a level of the tree?

Comment: I don't really see how this is a programming question. But one reason is to help decode any errors in your tree datastructure without having to write long tests since you can just visually see the problem with a small tree. Also, if you were to use induction, it becomes much easier to prove that your function works (might not be a formal proof but is enough to prove that your code works without having to deal with recursive/iterative based proofs such as invariants)